# Use of AJAX in C# .NET MVP web application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, mvp

I know this is a general question - however I want to gain a little advice before investing a lot of time looking into something that may not be suitable.

I have a C# .NET MVP web application, it needs to complete a new complex/heavy query when a user logs in (to find new messages for a user), however needs to do so without impacting performance. I have looked into multi threading in the past, however it would still need to wait until the new query completes, and adds a lot of complexity into the solution (we do not use multi threading currently).

I am wondering if Ajax would be a solution, so once the screen loads, is it possible to kick off an ajax command after page load that would execute and refresh part of the screen with the results?

How does the application handle if the user navigates to different screen? (note I planned to add the ajax component to master/base page which is part of every screen).

Would appreciate feedback, if people think its a possible approach I would do a proof of concept to prove it out.

Comment: Ajax would be ideally suited to this. If the user navigates away the query will still run on the server but the response obviously wont be handled by your JavaScript. No biggie really, it wont cause any client-side issues

Comment: Great, really appreciate the feedback, I just wanted to make sure it was viable solution. I will run a test and see if it could work in my solution! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't need to return result to client side you can use HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem to start the task then return it to client straight away.

If the query needs to return the result to client side then you need a to use Ajax call from client to server then update the view with data returned. You may want have a look at the client side framework such as angularJS.

Comment: This is useful info, the result is needed client side, so I will definitely look into angularJS. Thanks again, this gives me a running start.